# Improves hasBeenIdleForTooLong trace log correctness

Tags: neo4j

In neo4j-java-driver repository NettyChannelHealthChecker::hasBeenIdleForTooLong(...) trace is being logged without considering idleForTooLong flag.

I've created Pull Request with the change to improve hasBeenIdleForTooLong trace log correctness. 
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/pull/595/

It would be nice if contributors could merge this fix since it's very confusing when reading trace logs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is just a request to merge a pull request, not a question.

Comment: Sure, I agree. I thought it is a way to notify neo4j driver people.